# run codecept REST for yii2 how to get $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']?

Tags: rest, yii2, codeception

**Configure modules in api.suite.yml**

`class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - REST:
            url: http://xxxx
            depends: Yii2
        - \backend\tests\Helper\Api
    config:
        - Yii2`

**class UserLoginCest**

```
public function tryToTest(ApiTester $I)
{
    $I->haveHttpHeader('Authorization', 'Basic Og==');
    $I->sendPOST('/admin/user/login', ['username' => 'wen', 'password' => '123456']);
    $I->seeResponseCodeIs(\Codeception\Util\HttpCode::OK); // 200
    $I->seeResponseIsJson();
    $I->seeResponseContains('{"result":"ok"}');
}
```

**in UserController $behaviors**

```
$behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => CompositeAuth::class,
            'authMethods' => [
                [
                    'class' => HttpBasicAuth::class,
                    'auth' => function ($username, $password) {
                        $request = Yii::$app->request;
                        $username = $username ?: $request->post('username');
                        $password = $password ?: $request->post('password');
                        if (!$user = User::findByUsername($username)) {
                            return null;
                        }
                        if (!$user->validatePassword($password)) {
                            return null;
                        }
                        if ($user->login()) {
                            return $user;
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                ],
            ]
        ];
```

in Yii2 HttpBasicAuth

```
$username = isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) ? $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] : null;
    $password = isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) ? $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] : null;
```

var_dump($_SERVER) is not set $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] response 401 Unauthorized

Comment: Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.4.3
Powered by PHPUnit 7.1.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Comment: `class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - REST:
            url: http://xxxx
            depends: PHPBrowser
        - \backend\tests\Helper\Api
    config:
        - Yii2`

Answer (score 2):

Use `amHttpAuthenticated` method: https://codeception.com/docs/modules/REST#amHttpAuthenticated

```
$I->amHttpAuthenticated('username', 'password');
```

Comment: thow [ModuleException] REST::amNTLMAuthenticated: Not supported by functional modules

Comment: change api.suite.yml modules Yii2 to PHPBrowser，it's work